# Conditional formatting kableextra, group and color cell with maximum value

Tags: r, kableextra

I have a dataframe of the following format

[image]

Using kableExtra I want to group on the yr column, and then for ab and cd color the cell that has the maximum value.  Such that in ab the 3rd and 6th row will be red, in cd the 3rd and 5th. I tried something like

```
library(kableExtra)
sp %>% group_by(yr) %>%
mutate_if(is.numeric, function(x){
  cell_spec(x, "html", color  = ifelse(x >= lag(x) & x >= lead(x), "red", "green"))
} ) %>%
kable(format = "html", escape = F) %>%
kable_styling("striped", full_width = F)
```

But no dice. Any tips?

Reproducible dataframe

```
yr <- c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2005, 2005, 2005)
ab <- c(1, 6, 11, 12, 3 , 14)
cd <- c(3, 7, 19, 3, 77, 4)

sp <- as.data.frame(cbind(yr, ab, cd))
sp$ab <- as.numeric(sp$ab)
sp$cd <- as.numeric(sp$cd)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Change `mutate_if(...)` in your code to

```
mutate_if(is.numeric, ~ cell_spec(., "html", color=ifelse(.==max(.), "red", "green"))))
```

(In a modern writing manner of `dplyr`)

```
mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ cell_spec(., "html", color=ifelse(.==max(.), "red", "green"))))
```

which provides the following html table

```html
<table class="table table-striped" style="width: auto !important; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th style="text-align:right;"> yr </th>
   <th style="text-align:left;"> ab </th>
   <th style="text-align:left;"> cd </th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 2000 </td>
   <td style="text-align:left;"> <span style="color: green !important;">1</span> </td>
   <td style="text-align:left;"> <span style="color: green !important;">3</span> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 2000 </td>
   <td style="text-align:left;"> <span style="color: green !important;">6</span> </td>
   <td style="text-align:left;"> <span style="color: green !important;">7</span> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 2000 </td>
   <td style="text-align:left;"> <span style="color: red !important;">11</span> </td>
   <td style="text-align:left;"> <span style="color: red !important;">19</span> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 2005 </td>
   <td style="text-align:left;"> <span style=" color: green !important;">12</span> </td>
   <td style="text-align:left;"> <span style="color: green !important;">3</span> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 2005 </td>
   <td style="text-align:left;"> <span style=" color: green !important;">3</span> </td>
   <td style="text-align:left;"> <span style="color: red !important;">77</span> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 2005 </td>
   <td style="text-align:left;"> <span style="color: red !important;">14</span> </td>
   <td style="text-align:left;"> <span style="color: green !important;">4</span> </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you! something strange happens when I do this - it colors inconsistently across columns. For the first column, it only colors the max cell in instances where that cell happens to be the third row. In the second column in only colors the max cell when that cell happens to be in the second row etc (my actual dataset is much larger). Any idea why that may be?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't get your point... For your example data, *11* and *14* in **ab** column and *19* and *77* in **cd** column should be colored red, and the others green, then the rows that are colored red differs among columns. Just to make sure, I added the html table that will be provided by the code. Please check it and let me know if there's anything wrong.

Comment: It seems to work in this example - html you posted is colored correctly. But with actual data there is still an issue. Using the reproducible data as an example, what happens is that for ab 11 and 14 will be red because both of those happen to be in the third row (for the group). but for cd, for some reason it colors 77 red but not 19. Every instance in that column where the max is in the second row (for the group) gets colored red, but not otherwise. Does that make sense? Unfortunately the html is too long too long to post. Many thanks again!

Comment: sorry for the trouble - i seem to have discovered the issue. one of the variables i was grouping on was named with a space in it, such that when i was calling it I was using ' '. When I renamed it to a single word the problem, the code worked perfectly! Didnt know that could be a problem! thanks for the help

Comment: When there are spaces in a column name, we should put backquotes around it instead of quotes. Anyway, glad to hear that you solved the problem :)